# Storing Objective-C code in plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist

I know this sounds weird, but I would like to store and retrieve small snippets of Objective-C code from a plist. The scenario is this:

I have a plist that stores Core Image filter presets. This is all groovy for everything with numeric values (most of the presets). However, a few of the presets require something like "inputColor" which is a CIColor object (i.e. *[CIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0.75 blue:0.75]*). Is there any way to store something like that in a plist (either as a NSString or maybe NSData) and then retrieve it as usable code?

I realize a logical alternative would be to store the RGB value individually, but the former option would just be a bit more convenient as there are other macro values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want the plist file to be editable by humans?

If not, notice that `CIColor` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.  So you can convert it to an `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and store the `NSData` in the plist.  When you read the plist, you can convert the `NSData` back to a `CIColor` using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

In fact, `CIFilter` also conforms to `NSCoding`.  Perhaps you can just archive and unarchive your filter object.  It will automatically archive and unarchive its attributes.

Comment: That's the way to do it. Code sample are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could store it as a string and then parse it.

But why doing so? Convert the color to a NSData object and then store it in the plist file.